# ValueError: could not convert string to float: '"-0.33'と出てしまう

Tags: python

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '"-0.33'と出てしまいます
データはしたの写真です

[ブロック引用](https://wsdmoodle.waseda.jp/pluginfile.php/1550422/question/questiontext/5154458/1/15127316/polyreg.csv)

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn. linear_model import LinearRegression
arr2d_data = np.loadtxt(fname="/Users/ryotakumazawa/Desktop/]]]lp;:.........../polyreg.csv", delimiter=",")
array_x = arr2d_data[:, 0]
array_y = arr2d_data[:, 1]
list2d_X = []
for x in array_x:
    list2d_X+=[[x,x**2,x**3]]
arr2d_X= np.array(list2d_X)
reg = LinearRegression()
reg.fit(arr2d_X, array_y)
print('[0:.2f]'.format(reg.coef_[0]))
print('[O:.2f]'.format(reg.coef_[1]))
print('[0:.2f]'.format(reg.coef_[2]))
print('[0:.2f]'.format(reg.intercept_))
```

Comment: `polyreg.csv` が配置してあるリンク先にアクセスできないようです。

Comment: これと同件かも？ [python str型からのfloat型への変換](https://teratail.com/questions/117085)

Answer (score 0):

`f-strings` と `round()` 関数を使用できます。

```py
print(f"{round(reg.coef_[0],2)}")
print(f"{round(reg.coef_[1],2)}")
print(f"{round(reg.coef_[2],2)}")
print(f"{round(reg.intercept_,2)}")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print('[0:.2f]'.format(reg.coef_[0]))
print('[O:.2f]'.format(reg.coef_[1]))
print('[0:.2f]'.format(reg.coef_[2]))
print('[0:.2f]'.format(reg.intercept_))
```

コピー＆ペーストミスでないとしたら、

```
print('[O:.2f]'.format(reg.coef_[1]))
```

この行だけ`print('[0:2f]'...`ではなく`print('[O:2f]'...`になっているためではないでしょうか。0(ゼロ)とO(オー)見間違いやすいので、エディタのフォントで明確に違うものを使用するとかして工夫することも必要ではないかと思います。